# Polymorphic hasMany relationship in js-data

Tags: jsdata

is it possible to define a polymorphic hasMany relationship in js-data?

For example, a User has many animals, where an Animal can be a Cat or a Dog (ES6/TS `class Dog extends Animal`). If I request user.animals, I should receive a collection of cats and dogs, which may have their own custom properties.

I can't figure out from the docs how to setup my resource. Ember Data supports this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, its possible with js-data 2.0, http://www.js-data.io/docs/relations

Check these js-data hasMany example, would be quick hints for solve your problem

http://www.js-data.io/docs/examples#relations

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see it there. Can you give me an example? The animals array should contain Cat and Dog instances together, not just Animal instances.

Comment: To see this example you need to see output in console. The example is not covers the full cycle but most of it. In this example http://plnkr.co/edit/Fo1L0wOz5TtipPp8gz3v?p=info  post [see file post/1.json] has many comments [comment.json], the relation is in script.js, now what if every comment has different authors?

Comment: need another data structure author.json and confirm the relation in script,js? im also new to js-data. the community is not large.

Comment: The example does not use any inheritance and polymorphic at all.